# Android convert Layout to Bitmap and save it

Tags: performance

I'm trying to convert a RelativeLayout to Bitmap, and save it

But every time I run my code, I'm getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0`, I think I'm getting this because the layout wasn't displayed.

Is there a way to convert a RelativeLayout which has a TextView to Bitmap and save it?

My codes are:

Activity code

```
///////// Activity
////////Activity
TextView text;
    public bita(View view) {
        text= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("aaatest");
    }


        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            text.setText("clicked");


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a view, first you need to measure the view, then assign a size for it.